# textview is not displayed in gallery item and also there is space at beginning and end of every item

Tags: android, android-gallery

I want to display imageview and textview as a verticle item in gallery but textview is not displayed and also before first item and last item of gallery it contains space, how can I remove this space?

This is my code.

FilterActivity.java

```
public class FilterActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lstfilter;
    MyAdapter adapter;
    ImageView next,prev;
    Gallery horizontalscrollview;
    public static ArrayList<String> mylist;
    public static ArrayList<String> mycategorylist;
    HorizontalScrollView horizontalScroll;
    HorizontalScrollAdapter horizonAdapter;
    LinearLayout hlayout;
    ArrayList<Integer> array_image = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter);
        mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
        mycategorylist = new ArrayList<String>();
        horizontalscrollview = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.horizontalscrollview);
        horizontalscrollview.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
        hlayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.horizontal_menu);
        prev = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgprev);
        next = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgnext);
        lstfilter = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstfilter);
        mylist.add("Rs.250 n Below(253 result found)");
        mylist.add("Rs.251 - 500(25301 result found))");
        mylist.add("Rs.501 - 750(25301 result found))");
        mylist.add("Rs.501 - 750(25301 result found))");
        mylist.add("Rs.501 - 750(25301 result found))");
        mylist.add("Rs.501 - 750(25301 result found))");
        mylist.add("Rs.501 - 750(25301 result found))");
        mylist.add("Rs.501 - 750(25301 result found))");
        mylist.add("Rs.501 - 750(25301 result found))");
        mylist.add("Rs.501 - 750(25301 result found))");
        mylist.add("Rs.501 - 750(25301 result found))");
        mycategorylist.add("Brand");
        mycategorylist.add("Price");
        mycategorylist.add("Discount");
        mycategorylist.add("Availability");
        mycategorylist.add("More");

        array_image.add(R.drawable.img_brand);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.img_rupee);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.img_discount);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.yellow_check_mark);
        array_image.add(R.drawable.yellow_check_mark);

        horizonAdapter = new HorizontalScrollAdapter(this, mycategorylist,array_image);
        horizontalscrollview.setAdapter(horizonAdapter);


        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        prev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                horizontalscrollview = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.horizontalscrollview);
                    int firstVisibleItem = horizontalscrollview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                    int lastVisibleCount = horizontalscrollview.getLastVisiblePosition();
                    if (firstVisibleItem != 0) {
                        int count1 = firstVisibleItem
                                - (lastVisibleCount - firstVisibleItem);
                        if (count1 < 0) {
                            horizontalscrollview.setSelection(0);

                        }

                        else {
                            horizontalscrollview.setSelection(count1);

                        }
                        Log.d("item selected:",""+count1);
                        if(count1 == 0)
                        {
                            Log.d("first item visible","");
                            prev.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
                            next.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            prev.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                            next.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
                        }
                    }


                }
        });

        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              horizontalScroll.scrollTo(
//                      (int) horizontalScroll.getScrollX() + 10,
//                      (int) horizontalScroll.getScrollY());

                horizontalscrollview = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.horizontalscrollview);
                    int count = horizontalscrollview.getCount();
                    int firstVisibleItem = horizontalscrollview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                    int lastVisibleCount = horizontalscrollview.getLastVisiblePosition();
                    if (lastVisibleCount != count) {
                        int count1 = lastVisibleCount
                                + (lastVisibleCount - firstVisibleItem);
                        if (count1 > count) {
                            horizontalscrollview.setSelection(count);

                        } else {
                            horizontalscrollview.setSelection(count1);

                        }
                        Log.d("item selected:",""+lastVisibleCount);
                        if(count1 == lastVisibleCount)
                        {
                            Log.d("last item visible","");
                            prev.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                            next.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            prev.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                            next.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
                        }
                    }

                }

        });
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this, mylist);
        lstfilter.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

activity_filter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="#0088cc"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.10" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgDeliveryBack"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.28"
            android:background="@null"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/img_back_arrow" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txvdeliveryheader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:fontFamily="Roboto regular"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:text="Filter"
            android:textColor="#f8f8f8"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".9"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:text="@null"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgprev"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="#3374a3"
            android:src="@drawable/img_back_arrow" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:background="#168fcc"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Gallery
                android:id="@+id/horizontalscrollview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:background="@drawable/selected"
                android:columnWidth="70dp"
                android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgnext"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="#3374a3"
            android:src="@drawable/img_next" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstfilter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="340dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="#035f8d" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txvremove"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_trash_white"
                    android:text="@string/clear_filters"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="#000000" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_trash_white"
                    android:text="APPLY"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_horizontal_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#168fcc"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgcategory"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txvcategoryname"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#066da1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

HorizontalScrollAdapter.java

```
public class HorizontalScrollAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<String> data;
    ArrayList<Integer> image;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    // public ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public HorizontalScrollAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<String> list,ArrayList<Integer> image_array) {
        activity = a;
        data = list;
        image = image_array;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_horizontal_item, null);

        TextView txvfirst = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txvcategoryname); // title
        ImageView imgcategory = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgcategory);

        // HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // song = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        // title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_TITLE));
        // artist.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_ARTIST));
        // duration.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DURATION));
        // imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL),
        // thumb_image);
        txvfirst.setText(data.get(position));
        imgcategory.setImageResource(image.get(position));
        return vi;
    }
```

how can I display text below each image of gallery and I also want to remove space before and after each gallery item.

Comment: Hi nidhi, can you share your HorizontalScrollAdapter code as well? It's not clear where are you setting the text in textview.

Comment: added it please check it out.

Comment: cool, will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in your `activity_filter.xml` layout, the parent layout(`LinearLayout` here) for Gallery widget is having a fixed height of 40dp, if increase it or handle it with weights or something it will show the `TextView`. You can see, here I have increased that height to `100dp` and it shows the `TextView` clearly. And the space is coming because you have given `horizontalSpacing` as `5dp`, trying reducing that if you don't want the spaces between column.

**UPDATE:-**

I have updated my answer to remove spaces around `Gallery`, Here I have `RelativeLayout` and now the `Prev` and `Next` buttons are overlapping with gallery. Hope it solves your problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="#0088cc"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.10" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgDeliveryBack"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.28"
            android:background="@null"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_pass" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txvdeliveryheader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:fontFamily="Roboto regular"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:text="Filter"
            android:textColor="#f8f8f8"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".9"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:text="@null"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#168fcc"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Gallery
            android:id="@+id/horizontalscrollview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/drawer_shadow"
            android:columnWidth="70dp"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgprev"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_pass" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgnext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_like" />

</RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstfilter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="340dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="#035f8d" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txvremove"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_pass"
                            android:text="@string/abc_action_bar_home_description"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="#000000" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_like"
                android:text="APPLY"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but I am getting space before first item and after last item of gallery which is not removed by removing   android:horizontalSpacing="5dp" line from xml how I solve this problem?

Comment: you mean the space coming between your next/prev button and gallery right? I would suggest use a relativeLayout and have those button overlapping your gallery view. It will look better that way.

Comment: please send me example of it I am not able to do it getting space before first item of gallery and after last item of gallery.

Comment: Please check above I have updated the code in my answer.